# Convert csv into list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I got a CSV file where first row are headers, then other rows are data in columns.

I am using python to parse this data into the list of dictionaries

Normally I would use this code:

```
def csv_to_list_of_dictionaries(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        a = []
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True):
            a.append({k: v for k, v in row.items()})
        return a
```

but because data in one column are stored in dictionary, this code doesn't work (it separates key:value pairs in this dictionary

so data in my csv file looks like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,{'a':'b', 'c':'d'},'bla',sometimestamp
```

dictionary from this is created as this: `{col1:1, col2:{'a':'b', col3: 'c':'d'}, col4: 'bla'}`

What I wish to have as result is: `{col1:1, col2:{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}, col3: 'bla', col4: sometimestamp}`

Comment: There aren't a ton of standards around CSV, but your input looks broken. If you want to include commas in a single column, the most common solution is to quote the entire value, e.g. `1,"{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}",'bla',sometimestamp`. You might be able to tell the `csv` module to treat braces as quotes, but fixing the source is worth considering too.

Comment: I think `quotechar` can only be a single character; you won't be able to do something like `csv.DictReader(f, quotechar="{}")`. And actually, that wouldn't be what you want, either, since the braces should be part of the parsed result. Can you pre-process the file and replace `{` with `"{` and `}` with `}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the csv module use a regular expression to extract the fields from each row. Then make dictionaries from the extracted rows.

Example file:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,{'a':'b', 'c':'d'},'bla',sometimestamp
2,{'a':'b', 'c':'d'},'bla',sometimestamp
3,{'a':'b', 'c':'d'},'bla',sometimestamp
4,{'a':'b', 'c':'d'},'bla',sometimestamp
5,{'a':'b', 'c':'d'},'bla',sometimestamp
6,{'a':'b', 'c':'d'},'bla',sometimestamp
```

.

```
import re
pattern = r'^([^,]*),({.*}),([^,]*),([^,]*)$'
regex = re.compile(pattern,flags=re.M)

def csv_to_list_of_dictionaries(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        columns = next(f).strip().split(',')
        stuff = regex.findall(f.read())
    a = [dict(zip(columns,values)) for values in stuff]
    return a

stuff = csv_to_list_of_dictionaries(f)
```

---

```
In [20]: stuff
Out[20]: 
[{'col1': '1',
  'col2': "{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}",
  'col3': "'bla'",
  'col4': 'sometimestamp'},
 {'col1': '2',
  'col2': "{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}",
  'col3': "'bla'",
  'col4': 'sometimestamp'},
 {'col1': '3',
  'col2': "{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}",
  'col3': "'bla'",
  'col4': 'sometimestamp'},
 {'col1': '4',
  'col2': "{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}",
  'col3': "'bla'",
  'col4': 'sometimestamp'},
 {'col1': '5',
  'col2': "{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}",
  'col3': "'bla'",
  'col4': 'sometimestamp'},
 {'col1': '6',
  'col2': "{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}",
  'col3': "'bla'",
  'col4': 'sometimestamp'}]
```

---

Comment: but this is not solving the issue of getting ***{'a':'b', 'c':'d'}*** into the second column only and not splitting it up between second and third column

Comment: @marquillo - you are right, I must not have been paying attention. Sorry about that. Please see my edit.

Comment: ok, so I expanded the regex pattern and it worked for me, thanks

Comment: @marquillo - extended the regex pattern how? You can add to my answer if you would like.

Comment: your regex pattern was exactly for four "columns", so I had to prepare it for that number of columns, that I have in my csv file. So the code works, but not for random numbers of columns. Anyway, you gave me an idea, and that's important.